# How can I link multiple social logins in same federated ID AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, social-authentication

I have created a User pool and Federated Identities in AWS. Everything works fine I'm facing an issue, when I log in with google with abc@gmail.com an id is created in federated Identities, and when I log in with Facebook with abc@gmail.com I want to get them merged with the previous identity ID instead of creating a new one.

I'm using AWS amplify to get them authenticated

`Auth.federatedSignIn(provider, {}, {});`

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: Ever found an answer? I am curious about this as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found any answer yet. I think there is no solution for this.